# Using hibernate named parameter twice

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Assumed i have the following HQL

```
EntityManager.createQuery("SELECT a FROM a WHERE a.b = :par OR a.c = :par").setParameter("par", obj);
```

seems not to work. Does anybody have an idea how to solve this problem remain using only one parameter?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: No error. Resultlist is just empty.

Comment: do you have valid data? try to enable - showsql = true in persistence.xml and obtain the raw sql

Comment: Data is valid. When I use only left or right side of the "OR" everything works just fine

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure that it sets the first param right and then it just executes the query without the second one. You could set the parameter, like `*.setParameter(0, par)` and `*.setParameter(1, par)`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
setParameter(String name,Object val)
```

This is used to bind a value to the named parameter. But a name can occur multiple times in a query that doesn't matter. So check once whether you have really data for that query.

check the documentation [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setParameter%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29)

Some main text from that documentation

*Named query parameters are tokens of the form :name in the query string. A value is bound to the integer parameter :foo by calling
setParameter("foo", foo, Hibernate.INTEGER);
for example. A name may appear multiple times in the query string.*

If still u don't get the result then just try with using two names and set it

> EntityManager.createQuery("SELECT a FROM a WHERE a.b = :par1 OR a.c = :par2").setParameter("par1", obj).setParameter("par2", obj);

Comment: Well this is completly right. It seems that the query was kind of broken. The DBMS has an empty result list via native sql too. +1 For this good description

Answer (score 1):

```
setParameter(String name,Object val)
```

Replaces all occurence of name, specified in the query.