# Hibernate: search user by name whatever the order of firstname/lastname

Tags: hibernate, search

I have this (simplified) table `User`, binded to a POJO `User.java` thanks to Hibernate :

```
+---+------------+-------------+
|   | firstName  | lastName    |
+---+------------+-------------+
| 1 | John       | Doe         |
| 2 | John       | Poe         |
+---+------------+-------------+
```

In my UI, I have a search field to search users which suggests results related to what you are typing. By example if I type "`Jo`" in this search field it suggests me 2 results: "`John Doe`" and "`John Poe`". This works well.

Now I would like this search field to suggests me users whatever the order I used to type firstname and lastname. By example if I type "`Doe Jo`" it should suggests me "`John Doe`" as result.

Here is the query I use :

```
select u from User u
where lower(concat(u.lastName,' ',u.firstName)) like lower(:typedName)
or lower(concat(u.firstName,' ',u.lastName)) like lower(:typedName)
```

Where `typedName` is the text I entered in the search field. This parameter is incorpored in the query like this :

```
query.setParameter("typedName", typedName+'%');
```

- If I type "`Jo`", "`John`" or "`John D`" or more it finds me the good result(s)
- If I type "`D`" or "`Doe`" if finds me the good result(s)
- If I type "`Doe J`" or more **no result are found**.

Why does this last input couldn't find any result ? The first part of the my query's condition should be able to handle this as the second part is able to handle "`John D`", no ?

### Edit

As asked in the comments, this is how I execute my query :

```
final TypedQuery<User> query = getEntityManager()
    .createNamedQuery("my_query_name", User.class);
query.setParameter("typedName", typedName+'%');

try {
    return query.getResultList();
} catch (PersistenceException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); // for debug purpose
}
```

### Edit 2

Also note that the generated SQL retrieve me the good results for the last case

Comment: Does it work when you execute the produced SQL manually?

Comment: Just guessing: Your John Doe in the database is actually a "John" "Doe " (with an extra whitespace at the end)?

Comment: @DraganBozanovic: it works with the generated SQL, I have the expected results. How can the generated SQL retrieve the good results and the Hibernate query can't ?

Comment: @TobiasLiefke I checked and there are no extra whitespace for any users

Comment: This is very strange then. Just to be sure, could you try to trim the last name:  `lower(concat(trim(u.lastName),' ',u.firstName))`?

Comment: If the created SQL returns the correct results, it has to be how you create the query / extract the results (for example you use `setMaxResults(0)`). Could you add your method where you extract the results from the query?

Comment: @DraganBozanovic the usage of `trim()` doesn't change the result, but that could be a good point to keep for "exceptionnal cases". Thx for this btw

Comment: Checkout [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16251491/using-hibernate-named-parameter-twice). Usually you shouldn't have problems with using a named parameter twice (like mentioned in the answer) but I guess it's worth trying it with 2 parameter names.

Comment: Thx @Jan for this. I tried with 2 distinct parameters names but the result is the name. But as you said, it worth trying ;)

Comment: Please show us REAL code. Don't edit it or modify it **at all** before posting it, as this will hide the bug. Your query has a single parameter named "typedName", and the code used to execute the query binds a single parameter named "fullName". So, either it's real code, and you're not executing the right query, or it's fake code.

Comment: Hey @JBNizet, I updated my question according to your comment

Comment: When you checked for whitespaces, did you also check for other invisible "symbols"? Like line endings and stuff like that? Since no one answered yet I guess the fault is somewhere else. Did you log the query which hibernate creates and checked if it hits your expectations?