# Hibernate native SQL does not return correct result comparing to database

Tags: java, hibernate

I have this native query:

```
"SELECT DATE_FORMAT(createdDate, \"%Y-%M\") AS open_month, :" + filter 
+ " AS filterName, COUNT(id) AS counts from cases group by open_month, :" 
+ filter + " ;"
```

And then use `setResultTransformer` and `Transformers.aliasToBean` to convert to my DTO.

In database, Feb has two records using the query that Hibernate print out

```sql
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(createdDate, "%Y-%M") AS open_month,
    ? AS filterName,
    COUNT(id) AS counts
FROM
    cases
GROUP BY
    open_month,
    ?;
```

[image]

But when I get `query.list()`, 2017-Feb has only one record and the counts is 5, meaning that two records are merged.

Does anyone know why is this and how to return the exact result?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the same parameter will break the query like this: [Using hibernate named parameter twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16251491/using-hibernate-named-parameter-twice)

If I use different parameter names then it works fine